# Google Maps API - Update current location on map based on distance travelled

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Let's say i have set a walking route on google maps API from point A to point B.
I start at point A (duh). How can i, or is it possible, to update current location on map given the distance walked? (I'm getting distance walked from Google fit SDK).

Example:

From point A to point B is 1.5Km (A route marked on google maps)

I have ran 450m

How do i update map current position based on that?

PS: I can't use GPS as the app i'm making does not show your real current location. It's a false location

Answer (score 0):

ok it is possible but you need to have the bearing of your direction.
for this you need three things -

1. bearing of your movement from source to destination.
2. the source latlong.
3. the distance travelled.

if you have those 3 things then this is how you do it-

```
private LatLng getDestinationPoint (LatLng source,double brng, double dist){
        dist = dist / 6371;
        brng = Math.toRadians(brng);

        double lat1 = Math.toRadians(source.latitude), lon1 = Math.toRadians(source.longitude);
        double lat2 = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(dist) +
                Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(dist) * Math.cos(brng));
        double lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng) * Math.sin(dist) *
                        Math.cos(lat1),
                Math.cos(dist) - Math.sin(lat1) *
                        Math.sin(lat2));
        if (Double.isNaN(lat2) || Double.isNaN(lon2)) {
            return null;
        }
        return new LatLng(Math.toDegrees(lat2), Math.toDegrees(lon2));
    }
```

use my code from above function and put the arguments to function and in return you will get the destination latlng .

let me know if it was helpful to you.

thank you

Comment: This would be perfect if I had the movement bearing. Which unfortunately i don't.

 The only values I do have are distance travelled and all the data google maps api provides for route making (source and destination latlong included).

The idea was to pinpoint a marker on the map that updates accordingly with the distance travelled. That marker would have to follow the route set.

Thanks for your solution though.

Comment: So how do you know which direction you are going  ??  It is not just 1.5 km traveling .  There must be something  like 1.5 km south west or something like that.

Comment: The ideia is to make a route with google maps. It will make a "line" from point A to B. I want to follow that line

Comment: So tell me from where do get those two location A and B.  And from where do you get all the other data .  And be as specific as you can.  Tell me the function names...  And the case if possible.

Comment: I can't give you any functions yet because the point of my question is to know if it is possible to make this using google maps api or if i'm going to have to do it in other way. But i'l try to be detailed:
 The app is going to generate a walking route from Barcelona to Madrid (You don't need to do anything, it's all generated by the app).
I'm using google fit sdk to register the distance (using steps and height to estimate, no GPS). The objective is to make the marker move along the route accordingly with the distance recorded

Comment: Exmp: Walking route Barcelona-Madrid accordingly to Maps is 606 km. If you walked 303km (data from google fit sdk) the marker should be on half-way

Comment: ok . so you have a valid route which is from google , right ?

Comment: and you dont want to use gps. you will only say i have travelled 10 meter and show me where i am . right ?

Comment: you get it in json format right . so now for each step or way point you get different distances . and you can not exactly say 10 km . but if one turn is 9 km from source and another one is 12km from destination you can decide where to put the marker and tell a approx dist. as the json you get from google contains distance from each waypoint to another waypoint. you can take advantage of this data.

Comment: Ah nice! Using the waypoints of the route to keep the marker going. nice idea. If you can make an answer with that, ill accept it. Thank you!

Comment: this would be very long answer .

Comment: i will surely help you in the process. you first try something in it and tell me if you need anything.